# 8 puzzle Manhattan Distance

Tags: java, distance

for an 8 puzzle assignment we are needing to write a function for the [manhattan distance](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Manhattan_distance) between two 1d arrays. The user inputs the array containing the initial state of the array, and then the goal state of the array.  They both contain 8 ints and the 0 is meant to be a blank space.  I don't know where my code is wrong:

```
{
    for(int i =0; i< firstState.length-1; i++)
    {
        for(int j = i+1; j< firstState.length; j++)
        {
            if(firstState[i] == goalState[j])
            {
                result += Math.abs(firstState[i]-goalState[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(result);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: `result += Math.abs(firstState[i]-goalState[j]);`?  I think you used `i` instead of `j` in `goalState[]` array.

Comment: Please, give an explaination about what a specific term is next time. Not everyone is an expert in everything around here.

Comment: The return statement in the outer for loop makes the outer for loop pointless, and it is unclear what you mean by finding the Manhattan Distance of two arrays (I am only familiar with finding the Manhattan Distance of two points and the Wiki page linked only refers to between points).

Answer (score 0):

From the definition of [Manhattan Distance](https://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/manhattanDistance.html):

> The distance between two points measured along axes at right angles. In a plane with p1 at (x1, y1) and p2 at (x2, y2), it is |x1 - x2| + |y1 - y2|.

So, clearly you need to expand your `1d-array` to a `2d-board` to calculate the **Manhattan Distance**. You can do this by the following code:

```
for(int i=0; i<3; i+=1) {
    for(int j=0; j<3; j+=1) {
        if(firstState[(i*3)+j] != 0 && firstState[(i*3)+j] != goalState[(i*3)+j]) {
            bool found = false;
            for(int ii=0; ii<3; ii+=1) {
                for(int jj=0; jj<3; jj+=1) {
                    if(firstState[(i*3)+j] == goalState[(ii*3)+jj]) {
                        ret += (utils::_abs(i-ii) + utils::_abs(j-jj));
                        found = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(found) break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```